# How manage Theme value persistent in QwikJS

Tags: qwik, qwikjs

I'd like to handle the light/dark theme, but the code does not run on browser the first time

```js
useTask$(({ track }) => {
    track(() => themeAppearance.value);
    if (isBrowser) {
      const savedTheme = localStorage.getItem("themeApp");
      console.log("from local storage", savedTheme);
      if (savedTheme) {
        themeAppearance.value =
          savedTheme === "dark" ? ThemeTypes.Dark : ThemeTypes.Ligth;
        return;
      }
    }
  });
```

only if i change the themeAppearance with the button with this function from useThemeHook

```js
const toggleAppearance$ = $(() => {
    console.log(themeAppearance.value);

    if (themeAppearance.value === ThemeTypes.Dark) {
      themeAppearance.value = ThemeTypes.Ligth;
      backGroundPrimaryColor.value = BackdrounColor.Ligth;
      backGroundSecondaryColor.value = BackdrounColor.Ligth;

      textColorPrimary.value = TextColor.HardTextLigthBackground;
      textColorSecondary.value = TextColor.LigthTextLigthBackground;

      localStorage.setItem("themeApp", ThemeTypes.Ligth);
      return;
    }

    if (
      themeAppearance.value === ThemeTypes.Ligth &&
      panelBackground === "solid"
    ) {
      themeAppearance.value = ThemeTypes.Dark;
      backGroundPrimaryColor.value = BackdrounColor.DarkPrimarySolid;
      backGroundSecondaryColor.value = BackdrounColor.DarkSecondarySolid;

      textColorPrimary.value = TextColor.HardTextDarkBackground;
      textColorSecondary.value = TextColor.LigthTextDarkBackground;

      localStorage.setItem("themeApp", ThemeTypes.Dark);

      return;
    }

    if (
      themeAppearance.value === ThemeTypes.Ligth &&
      panelBackground === "translucent"
    ) {
      themeAppearance.value = ThemeTypes.Dark;
      backGroundPrimaryColor.value = BackdrounColor.DarkPrimaryTranslucent;
      backGroundSecondaryColor.value = BackdrounColor.DarkSecondaryTranslucent;

      textColorPrimary.value = TextColor.HardTextDarkBackground;
      textColorSecondary.value = TextColor.LigthTextDarkBackground;

      localStorage.setItem("themeApp", ThemeTypes.Dark);

      return;
    }
  });
```

I tried using `useVisibleTask$()` but it doesn't work for me because it runs after the first render so it's going to be a bad user experience its first render with default theme dark and then change to light saved theme

Comment: If you will put theme in localstorage you will always get the problem of default theme render first and then switch to user prefer theme in the browser even you will use useTask$. If you want to prevent from this put theme configurations in redis or other cache on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try enabling [eagerness](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/components/tasks/#option-eagerness)?

```js
useVisibleTask$(
  () => {
    const savedTheme = localStorage.getItem("themeApp");
    console.log("from local storage", savedTheme);
    if (savedTheme) {
      themeAppearance.value =
        savedTheme === "dark" ? ThemeTypes.Dark : ThemeTypes.Ligth;
      return;
    }
  },
  { strategy: 'document-ready' }
);
```